# Rails 3 - undefined method `where' for #<User:0x00000104c69b98>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, where-clause, conditional-statements

I have following helper method:

```
  def orders_chart_series(orders, start_time)
    orders_by_day = orders.where(:created_at => start_time.to_date..Date.today).
                    group("date(created_at)").
                    select("created_at, count(id) as total_price")
    (start_time.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
      order = orders_by_day.detect { |order| order.created_at.to_date == date }
      order && order.total_price.to_f || 0
    end.inspect
  end
```

and I am still getting the error in the name of this thread. I tried to print the content of the **orders** parameter and I got this one:

```
#<User:0x00000104c69b98>
```

What mean this problem? I try to search a solution of this problem, but I still do know how to fix it.
I tried also replace the command **where** for **conditions**, but still the same.

I'll be very grateful for every help about this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to call `where` on a `User`-instance, instead of on the `User`-class (`where` is a class-method). You could change `orders.where` to `orders.class.where`.

(It's also a bit confusing to have a single User instance in a variable called orders, but that might just be me.)

Comment: Thank you, it works me. This part of code is from Ryan Bates's tutorial, and about weird names - I just tried it, how this example work.